# Fresh database and Django manage.py shell and syncdb are not running

Tags: python, django, postgresql, shell

MY Django Project is running Good and I want to remove my DB and create new one to test Some Functionalities in my Code.After Creating a fresh Postgre
SQL DB .I run the ./manage.py syncdb and shell , i also tried other commands like flush but the result is same as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 70, in handle_noargs
    get_models()
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 232, in get_models
    self._populate()
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/models.py", line 9, in <module>
    dt_settings.patch_all()
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 232, in patch_all
    patch_root_urlconf()
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 220, in patch_root_urlconf
    reverse('djdt:render_panel')
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 480, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 310, in app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 262, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 346, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 341, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/ashok/newproject/pflat/jntu/urls.py", line 11, in <module>
    url(r'^base/', include('base.urls')),
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 26, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/ashok/newproject/pflat/base/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from base import views
  File "/home/ashok/newproject/pflat/base/views.py", line 35, in <module>
    @cr('Base/CSV Import')
  File "/home/ashok/newproject/pflat/role/role_contrib.py", line 56, in cr_dec
    role = gr(role_name)
  File "/home/ashok/newproject/pflat/role/role_contrib.py", line 28, in gr
    return Role.objects.filter(name = role_name)[0]
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 132, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 96, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 710, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 781, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/ashok/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "role_role" does not exist
LINE 1: ...role_role"."description", "role_role"."date" FROM "role_role...
```

Djano Version:1.6.2

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'base',
'registration',
'course',
'south',
'chosen',
'accounts',
'prephd',
'role',
'resmet',
'messages',
'materializecssform',
'debug_toolbar',
```

)

Comment: can share settings.py code

Comment: looks like you module with model Role doesn't enabled in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: role is specified in INSTALLED_APPS ,i think the problem is tag descriptors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790344/django-1-7-lazy-evaluation-to-avoid-app-registry-isnt-ready-yet-in-models-py

Comment: How did you remove the previous DB ?

Comment: Access Postgres DB and  dropdb DBNAME

Answer (score 1):

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "role_role" does not exist
```

Check INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py, you are missing an application

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'base',
    'registration',
    'course',
    'south',
    'chosen',
    'accounts',
    'prephd',
    'role',
    'messages',
    'materializecssform',
    
)

Comment: I think problem with tag descriptor and i try erase the cache memory but i do n't know how to erase cache for django , check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790344/django-1-7-lazy-evaluation-to-avoid-app-registry-isnt-ready-yet-in-models-py

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not Providing the information of INSTALLED_APPS .

My Problem is solved after i remove debug_toolbar from my INSTALLED_APPS